# Butterknife is not initializing views in AOSP marshmallow but works fine in lollipop

Tags: android, android-source, android-6.0-marshmallow, butterknife, android-jack-and-jill

I am using butterknife library in my project. It works fine in when I build in Lollipop AOSP but the same code initializes nothing and so after that NPE is thrown in Marshmallow AOSP.

Here is the code:

```
public class ErrorLayoutViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.error_content_container)
    View errorContentLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.error_message)
    TextView errorMessage;
    @Bind(R.id.retry_button)
    View retryButton;

    public ErrorLayoutViewHolder(final View itemView, View.OnClickListener retryListener) {
        super(itemView);
        retryButton.setOnClickListener(retryListener);
    }
}
```

This is the parent class **ViewHolder.java**:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    final public View itemView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        this.itemView = itemView;
        itemView.setTag(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke     virtual method 'void  android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
02-25 20:38:57.538  5922  5922 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.micromax.aroundyou.model.ui.viewholders.ErrorLayoutViewHolder.<init>(ErrorLayoutViewHolder.java:38)
```

**Line 38**:

```
 retryButton.setOnClickListener(retryListener);
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: You should call `ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);` before line 38

Comment: ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView); is in the parent class constructor which is called before line 38

Comment: Then you should have the bind statement in the parent class. What you are doing is similar to trying to assign child class variable from parent class!

Comment: Problem is that this code works fine in lollipop aosp but not in marshmallow aosp

Comment: oh.. then I believe it's something the creators of the library should take a look at. Have you tried raising an issue on their github repo?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cast the view to a button or whatever custom view you are using.
Did you try to use [Butterknife's](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

`@OnClick(R.id.retry_button) void foo(){
//TODO button logic
}`

? This way you do not care about the class of the view at all.

Comment: But when I remove the button and try to change the visibility of textview (errorMessage), it also throws NPE

Comment: Did you check if the errorMessage is not null when you try to display it? If you are sure that it is not null then try this : `errorMessage.setText(String.valueOf(yourerror))`. If this is not the issue then check your layout and make sure you have the views of everything you try to bind.

Comment: Problem is that this code works fine in lollipop aosp but not in marshmallow aosp

Comment: Recently, I found that jack compiler is used in marshmallow and so butterknife is not working. I did the same thing in android studio gradle file. I added a line:    useJack true. How this problem can be solved?